# Setup local GIT server for AOSP development

Tags: git, gitlab, android-source

I am finding options to setup a local GIT server for AOSP development. Below are the findings I have:

Option 1:

- Setup Gitlab on my local server
- Use the import project via URL to create the manifest project.
- Provide the chosen manifest file to import via manifest option to create all the projects making up the AOSP.( The chosen manifest will be edited to be understood by Gitlab)
- Clone from Gitlab on the client and develop.

Problems:
- How to get updates to the manifest project and other existing projects? I have to setup either mirroring from the individual repositories.

Option 2:

- Setup Gitlab on my local server
- Clone the AOSP sources (mirror option) from the command line.
- Use the Gitlab rake utility to create projects in Gitlab
- Clone from Gitlab on the client and develop.

Problems:
- How to get updates to the manifest project and other existing projects? I have to setup a remote for all the projects, which doesn't sound convincing enough.

Option 3:

No Gitlab. Completely based on command line.

Problems:
- Not user friendly with respect to managing issues, bugs and feature requests.

I would like to have thoughts from the community on my findings. Do suggest if I have missed out an option.